# margins and right align footer tcpdf

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

I am working on generating content for an invoice but i need to have all my 'divs' in alignment - header, body, and footer. Currently i have the header and body in alignment but the footer's margins dont seem to align plus i have two cells - one left aligned and the other right aligned. However they don't align plus their margins are off.

```
public function Footer()
{
    $this->SetY(-15);
    $this->SetFont(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, ' ', 8);
    $this->SetFooterMargin(15);

    //Get time
    $date = date('m/d/Y');
    $time = date('H:i:s A');

    $this->Cell(0, 0, 'Date: '.date("Y-m-d")." - Time: ".$time , 0, false, 'L');
    // Page number
    $this->Cell(0, 0, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'R', 0, '', 0, true, 'T', 'M');
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Within the footer function, call this

```
$this->SetRightMargin(N); // Where N is the value of the margin spacing you like to achieve
```

Hope this helps